# How to import notes to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, notes.app

I have an iPhone 6S running 10.1.1 and I have some notes to import to my device. I don't know how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using iCloud Drive or your PC or your mac. Below link has decribed simply how you can do that and which files support. If your file type is not listed in that list, then you have to convert it before importing.

https://support.apple.com/en-lk/HT205793

Thanks